# How am I able to separate a DataFrame into many DataFrames, based on a label and then do computation for each DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

[image: 1]

I am trying to make one DataFrame for each unique value in df1['Tub']. Right now I am creating a dictionary and trying to append to each new DataFrame instances where there is a matching Tub. I think my logic is on the right track.

```
tub_df = {}

tubs = []

for tub in df1['Tub']:
    if tub not in tubs:
        tubs.append(tub)
#['Tub 1', 'Tub 2', 'Tub 3']

for tub_name in tubs:
    for tub_row in df1['Tub']:
        if tub_row == tub_name:
            tub_df[tub] = pd.DataFrame.copy(df1.loc[tub_row])
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question title and particularly the "and do computation for each data frame" part, it sounds like you're looking for pandas groupby feature. For example if you wanted to compute the mean of all columns for each Tub you could do:

```
df1.groupby('Tub').agg('mean')
```

Or if you wanted to purely loop through each group as a separate dataframe:

```
for key, group in df1.groupby('Tub'):
    # Do some calculation where key is the Tub and group is a data frame containing values for matching tubs
    print(key, group)
```

**EDIT for additional ask:**
To apply a generic function to each group you can define the function and then use `pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply` e.g.:

```py
def drop_last(frame):
    return frame.iloc[:-1,:]

df1.groupby('Tub').apply(drop_last)
```

This will return a single dataframe with the last item from each group removed.

Comment: How would I, for example, delete the last row from each DataFrame (containing each unique tub)?

Comment: See edit, it would be great if you accepted the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shorter version, identify unique values in `Tub` & use dict comprehension to create a filtered `dict`

```
{tub: df1[df1.Tub.eq(tub)] for tub in df1.Tub.unique()}
```